# Rosbag not playing back on Odroid board!

Tags: robotic-arm, ros, rosbag, ros-hydro, odroid

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everybody!

I was planning to test some of my packages on the ARM-based Odroid-XU (ROS hydro on Linaro 13.05), but experienced some strange behavior when trying to play back a bag file.

When I execute the command `rosbag play mybag.bag`, I get the following output:

```
[ INFO] [1385631615.554476003]: Opening mybag.bag

Waiting 0.2 seconds after advertising topics... done.

Hit space to toggle paused, or 's' to step.
```

The problem is that it **never** got to the stage that it would say:

```
[RUNNING]  Bag Time: 1381311745.123451   Duration: {time} / 78.856356
```

But as soon as I quit with `ctrl+c`, it will display:

```
[RUNNING]  Bag Time: 1381311666.267094   Duration: 0.000000 / 78.856356     
^C
```

I tried fiddling around with the different options and had a minor success with `-i` (play back all messages without waiting). With this option the bag is plays back in a couple of seconds. I think it is interesting that this works, however it does not help in my case.

I have also tried different bags, all of them have been extensively used on my workstation.

Has anyone else experienced this problem? Any clue about how to fix this?

Best

Tim

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/105581/rosbag-not-playing-back-on-odroid-board!/) by [timster](https://answers.ros.org/users/3358/timster/) on ROS Answers with karma: 396 on 2013-11-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is due to a bug in rosbag.

It's fixed in https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/pull/311 , which hasn't been released or built for ARM yet. I recommend building ros_comm from source.

**EDIT**

This is fixed in the latest builds of ROS for ARM. Note that the repository URL has changed; see: http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/UbuntuARM

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2013-12-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1